# The normal cone to a singular subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be a smooth variety, and let $X\subset Y$ be a subvariety. If $X$ is smooth, then $C_XY=N_XY$ is a quotient of $TY|_X$. Is the same still true if $X$ is singular? I.e. is there always a surjection
$$TY|_X\to C_XY.$$
A related question: for the normal cone I have the following vague picture in mind: it is  a union of closures of normal cones to smooth strata in some "equisingular" stratification of $X$. Is there a precise sense in which this is true?

Comment: wouldn't such a surjection require the normal cone to be irreducible?